# typescript redux: how to reduce boilerplate with typesafe-actions

Tags: typescript, redux, typesafe-actions

I'm using typescript with typesafe-actions.
My codebase has a lot of repeated code like the following:
I've looked through similar questions but couldn't find an answer.

How can I reduce the boilerplate.

```
import { action, ActionType, createAction } from 'typesafe-actions';

interface ModelA {
  stuff: string
}

export enum FeatureAActionTypes {
  Load = '[FeatureA] Load',
  Success = '[FeatureA] Success',
  Fail = '[FeatureA] Fail',
  Reset = '[FeatureA] Reset'
}

export const FeatureAActions = {
  load: createAction(FeatureAActionTypes.Load),
  success: (response: ModelA[]) => action(FeatureAActionTypes.Success, response),
  fail: (error: string) => action(FeatureAActionTypes.Fail, error),
  reset: createAction(FeatureAActionTypes.Reset)
};

export type FeatureAAction = ActionType<typeof FeatureAActions>;

interface ModelB {
  differentStuff: string
}

export enum FeatureBActionTypes {
  Load = '[FeatureB] Load',
  Success = '[FeatureB] Success',
  Fail = '[FeatureB] Fail',
  Reset = '[FeatureB] Reset'
}

export const FeatureBActions = {
  load: createAction(FeatureBActionTypes.Load),
  success: (response: ModelB[]) => action(FeatureBActionTypes.Success, response),
  fail: (error: string) => action(FeatureBActionTypes.Fail, error),
  reset: createAction(FeatureBActionTypes.Reset)
};

export type FeatureBAction = ActionType<typeof FeatureBActions>;
```

Comment: Are the actions handled asynchronously (e.g. by a call to the server, maybe handled by a thunk or a saga or something)?  Because if so you could possibly look at `createAsyncAction` [https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#createasyncaction](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions#createasyncaction).

Answer (score 0):

Given that the library is already designed to reduce boilerplate code, the more you can stick to the API, the less boilerplate code you need to write.  If you use the built in `createReducer` API, there's a way to obviate the need to define your action types as strings.  That is, they're extrapolated from the action creators returned from `createAction`.

That you're keeping those separate *seems* to imply you're using your own reducers which is almost certainly why you're also exporting all the `FeatureXAction` types.  This could be done at the end, rather than individually, but would really only save you the one line per file and you'd still need to aggregate them at the end.  All this will add verbosity and boilerplate.

Before typesafe-actions, we had even more boilerplate than you as each of our actions were defined by an interface and then each action creator returned an implementation of that interface.  While it was very explicit, it was VERY verbose.